# Can I make my Telegram autoreply bot not reply to one particular person?

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, userid, aiogram

I am using python:

```
@dp.message_handler(content_types=['text', 'video', 'audio', 'photo', 
                                   'document', 'voice', 'animation'],
                    is_forwarded = False,
                    user_id = not(userlist))

async def check(message):
    await message.reply("Thank you for your enquiry.)
```

The user list is the `user_id` of the person I want my bot to NOT autoreply to.

Answer (score 0):

You can provide a `filter` function to the `message_handler` that will exclude some id's:

```
userlist = [ 1234, 6789 ]
accessChecker = lambda message: message.from_user.id not in userlist
```

Add it to your `message_handler` like so:

```
@dp.message_handler(accessChecker)
@dp.message_handler(
    content_types=['text', 'video', 'audio', 'photo', 'document', 'voice', 'animation'],
    is_forwarded = False,
)
```

---

For more info about combining multiple filters, check the [documentation](https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/dispatcher/index.html#available-handlers).